# Node + Mongodb + ObjectId not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working with nodejs+ express and mongodb.

I am using postman and access the API.
When I use **ObjectId** the server not responding anything. If i removed means working good.
I am not able to fix this issue. Please can anyone help for this.

test.js

```
//Post Data:
{
    "list_id": "56963e4dbcd5d4ff27ced0fbd"
}


var app = require('express');
var router = app.Router();
var server = require('./../../server');
var mongoUtil = require('./../../mongoUtil');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

router.post('/share', function(req, res, next) {

    var data = {
        query : {}
    };
    console.log(req.body['list_id']);
    //printed  56963e4dbcd5d4ff27ced0fbd

    console.log(data.query);
    //printed {}

    data.query = ObjectId(req.body['list_id']);
    console.log(data.query);
    //Here not getting any response
    // this line not printed and server no response.
    //Also tried the following things. but its not working.
    // data.query['_id']  = new ObjectID(req.body['list_id']);
    //data.query._id = ObjectId(req.body['list_id']);

    var collection = mongoUtil.list;
    collection.findOne(data.query, function(err, list) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(list);
        if (!err && list) {
            res.send("Sucess");
            return;
        } else {
            res.send("Error");
            return;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What error you are getting when you include ObjectID?

Comment: I didn't get any error. The server not responding.

Comment: `ObjectId()` constructor expects a 24 byte hex string, 12 byte binary string or a Number as its argument, yet here `req.body['list_id']` is just a plain string.

Comment: @chridam - I tried list_id is "56963e4dbcd5d4ff27ced0fbd" but its not working

Comment: What do you get if you run the statement `console.log(ObjectId(req.body['list_id']));` before the other `console.log(data.query);` statement? I'm pretty sure you meant `data.query['_id'] = ObjectId(req.body['list_id']);`, correct?

Comment: You need to `new` the ObjectId .   `data.query = new ObjectId(req.body['list_id']);`

Comment: What is `mongoUtil.list`?

Comment: @chridam -  If  run the statement console.log(ObjectId(req.body['list_id'])); means the server not responding anything. Also I updated the question .

Comment: @robertklep In mongoUtil js just db connection

Comment: I am sure mongoUtil is not a problem

Comment: @RSKMR it should be `collection.findOne({ _id : ObjectId(...) }, function(err, doc) { ... })`. If that doesn't call the callback, I have my doubts about `collection` being valid.

Comment: @robertklep I removed this code. but working. ======>  var collection = mongoUtil.list;
    collection.findOne(data.query, function(err, list) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(list);
        if (!err && list) {
            res.send("Sucess");
            return;
        } else {
            res.send("Error");
            return;
        }
    });

Comment: Shit -  I done mistake in id length. sorry. How can validate this?

Comment: @RSKMR [`ObjectID.isValid()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/ObjectID.html#.isValid)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111756/discussion-between-rskmr-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`56963e4dbcd5d4ff27ced0fbd` should be of length 24. But it is 25. Make sure it is 24. It might work.

```
ObjectID()
Constructor
Create a new ObjectID instance

class ObjectID()
Arguments:  
id (string) – Can be a 24 byte hex string, 12 byte binary string or a Number.
Returns:    
object instance of ObjectID
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't need `new`.

Comment: Haha nice catch! Someone apparently isn't logging any errors that the server is throwing, because otherwise they would have caught it...

Answer (score 0):

Caught with the same error. Seems like `ObjectId` from mongoDB not working.

FOllowing import fixed the issue:
import { ObjectId } from "bson"